# JavaScript sequential async function calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise, jquery-deferred

I have an array of functions, which making some logic asynchronously (e.g. ajax calls). How does look like function, which will sequentially call functions from array?

```
var saveHandlers = [];

saveHandlers.push(function () {
   var deferred = $.Deferred();

   setTimeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve();
   }, 2000);

   return deferred.promise();
});

saveHandlers.push(function () {
   var deferred = $.Deferred();

   setTimeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve();
   }, 2000);

   return deferred.promise();
});

$(function () {
    var $form = $('#form');

    $form
       .unbind('submit')
       .submit(function (e) {
          if (saveHandlers.length > 0) {
              $.when.apply(null, saveHandlers);
          }
          e.preventDefault();
       });
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us what you have tried. So we can start from that to discuss you issue.

Comment: @Archer Let's take that an array consists of **Promises**, but it's length is dynamic. How main function can be look like?

Comment: @Andrea I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which calls you async function and takes the array index as an argument.

In the callback for the async function, increment the index and (if you haven't got to the end of the array) call the function recursively with the new index.

```
var foo = [fun_a, fun_b, fun_c];

function bar(index) {
    index = index || 0;

    function callback() {
        if (foo[++index]) {
           bar(index);
        }
    };

    foo[index]().then(callback);
}
```